# Jailkit inside /home path

Tags: 18.04, server

I've seen several guides but they all use a path other than /home, for example /jail, /var/jail or /home/jail
https://www.howtoforge.com/debian-9-jail-jailkit/

I tried replacing /jail with /home but it doesn't seem to work, do you have any suggestions on that?

I need the user to be in /home/user and not in /jail/user

Comment: I need the user to be in /home/user and not in /jail/user

Comment: It is best to put the more info in the question not as a comment.

Comment: Thanks @David, edited

Comment: What have you tried? What errors do you get?